# customize drupal access denied page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have many basic pages where I need the user to be logged-in in order to see it. So i want to customize this access denied page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Configuration -> System -> Site Information.

From there you can set the access denied page (403) to be any path you want.

You could create a page node, and then set this path to be your new node.